# True or false: $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)=a\Rightarrow \lim_{x \to a}f(f(x))=a$?

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, solution-verification, definition

The question is proove or give a counter exemple to this statement: $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)=a\Rightarrow \lim_{x \to a}f(f(x))=a$

The correct answer is false see a counter exemple below.

Comment: Check your definition of a limit. The existence and value of $ \lim_{x \to a} f(x) $ doesn't tell you anything about $ f(a) $.

Comment: ‏@nasekatnasushi so the answer is that it's false?

Comment: @nasekatnasushi I don't see $f(a)$ written once in the question.

Comment: @legionwhale indeed it is not question if f(x) is define or not in $a$

Comment: It is true for continuous maps, not sure about having no assumptions on $f$.

Comment: The proof is almost correct with your definition of a limit at a point. But the [usual definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#(ε,_δ)-definition_of_limit) requires only that $|f(x) - a| < \epsilon|$ for $0 < |x-a| < \delta$, i.e. the point $x=a$ is excluded.

Comment: It is preferable to exclude the point of convergence, otherwise the existence of the limit will depend on a given point. We'd unnecessarily require the function to be defined at that point, for instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Counter example: let $b \neq a$ and
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
a & \text{if } x \neq a \\
b & \text{if } x = a
\end{cases}
$$
then
$$
\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = a
$$
but
$$
f(f(x)) = f(a) = b, \quad \forall x\neq a
$$
then
$$
\lim_{x\to a}f(f(x)) = b
$$

Comment: The limit exists and is equal to $a$. Think of $f(x)$ defined in say $(-1,1)$ to be $0$ everywhere else and $f(0)=1$. Then $f(x) \to 0$ as $x\to 0$.

Comment: @legionwhale I think you are confusing the existence of a limit at a point and continuity at the point.

Comment: @enzotib the limit can exist in $a$ but be different that $f(a)$. In other words $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)=l\neq f(a)$

Comment: @AlvinL The example you've given is qualitatively different to the answer, but I see now (following Greg Martin's comment to the question) that I accidentally remembered a non-standard definition of limits for functions. I apologise; with the standard definition, this is indeed a counterexample.

Comment: @X0-user-0X I cannot understand why this comment addressed to me, I never said that

Comment: @enzotib I mean in the expression $lim _{x \to a} f(f(x))$ it seems to me that $x$ is laways different from $a$ so the limit is still a as $x$ NEVER equals to $a$

Comment: @legionwhale $f(x) \to 0$ as $x\to 0$ and $f(f(x)) \to 1$ as $x\to 0$. It's exactly the same argument, I just fixed $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @X0-user-0X please read carefully my definition of $f(x)$ and consequent reasoning on $f(f(x))$

Answer (score 1):

You write $\lim _{y\to a} f(y) = a$ and later use this argument with the substitution $y=f(x)$. Your attempt is circular.

What you will have proved is
$$ \lim _{x\to a} f(x) = a \Rightarrow \lim _{f(x) \to a} f(f(x)) = a \quad\text{(which is obvious)} $$
But this is not always the same as
$$ \lim _{x\to a} f(x) = a \Rightarrow \lim _{x \to a} f(f(x)) = a $$

We are required to show that for an appropriate $\delta>0$ we have
$$ 0<|x-a|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(f(x)) - a|< \varepsilon. $$
But we only know that there is a $\delta _1$ satisfying
$$ 0<|x-a|<\delta _1 \Rightarrow |f(x) - a|< \varepsilon. $$
Without further assumptions on $f$ I don't see a way to make progress.